# update json column with timestamp pyspark

Tags: pyspark

```
+----------------+
|application_name|    
+----------------+
|{"application_name": "DIMENSIONS_USER",
  "dq_test_name": "contra_cp_dimension_agentpresence_isBillable_should_be_set"
}
+----------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

In this i need to update column value with date for all the rows..can someone help I am new to pyspark and was unable to find any working solution

```
+----------------+
|application_name|    
+----------------+
|{"application_name": "DIMENSIONS_USER",
  "dq_test_name": "contra_cp_dimension_agentpresence_isBillable_should_be_set",
"date":01/001/2020
}
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a UDF that will add a new value to json string.

Here's an example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import json


def update_app_data(data):
    app_data = json.loads(data)
    app_data["date"] = "01/001/2020"
    return json.dumps(app_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
    application_data = {
        "application_name": "DIMENSIONS_USER",
        "dq_test_name": "contra_cp_dimension_agentpresence_isBillable_should_be_set",
    }
    data = [
        {
            "application_name": json.dumps(application_data),
        }
    ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
    update_app_data_udf = F.udf(lambda x: update_app_data(x))
    df = df.withColumn("application_name", update_app_data_udf(F.col("application_name")))
```

Input dataframe looks like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|application_name                                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"application_name": "DIMENSIONS_USER", "dq_test_name": "contra_cp_dimension_agentpresence_isBillable_should_be_set"}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|application_name                                                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"application_name": "DIMENSIONS_USER", "dq_test_name": "contra_cp_dimension_agentpresence_isBillable_should_be_set", "date": "01/001/2020"}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: {"application_name": "DIMENSIONS_USER",
  "dq_test_name": "contra_cp_dimension_agentpresence_isBillable_should_be_set",
"date":01/001/2020
}
need output like this in one column only

Comment: @user3749031 I thought that you have multiple json objects, that's why I gave you an example with a JSON file. I updated the example.

Comment: I had updated the question.....this will make thing more clear..... I only need to update the column which contains json to add the date

Comment: can you check now

Comment: @user3749031 Ah, got it! Updated.

Comment: seems this should work..... I will try this....thanks once again :)

Comment: @user3749031 You're welcome. Good luck! :)

Comment: facing below error do you have any idea
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o222.__getnewargs__. Trace:

Comment: @user3749031 What are you trying to do? The example that I provided works. Are you running that or something else?

Comment: http://collabedit.com/7w7wq
This is the code which I am trying to execute

Comment: Please post pastebin link, I'm not sure what collabedit is.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uCmJDnAN Please check this one...

Comment: @user3749031 This has nothing to do with this question or example that I showed you, please post a new question and explain in detail what's going on and what are you trying to do.

Comment: okay....will try to resolve or else will post as new question in detail..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238259/discussion-between-user3749031-and-vlad-siv).